# Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Tags: permissions, npm

I was updating NPM, Node, and Vue (a javascript framework).  I think somewhere I changed the permissions to a directory to root root.  I am trying to run

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

I get a string of

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/
```

The owner of node_modules was root:root and I changed it to root:staff.  I also made sure I was in the staff group.  For some reason I am still getting Missing write access.  I also chmod 775 -R.  And then reboot to make sure the new permissions loaded but still having trouble installing the Vue CLI.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As describe on [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#manually-change-npms-default-directory) you can:

1. Back up your computer.
2. On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:
   `mkdir ~/.npm-global`
3. Configure npm to use the new directory path:
   `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
4. In your preferred text editor, open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:
   `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
5. On the command line, update your system variables:
   `source ~/.profile`
6. To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo:
   `npm install -g jshint`

Instead of steps 2-4, you can use the corresponding ENV variable (e.g. if you don’t want to modify ~/.profile):
`NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global`